# Service Fabric becomes unavailable after update to latest (6.1.456.9494)

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have two main symptoms of a larger problem.

1. If I'm debugging an application in visual studio every once in a while I'll have it on a breakpoint and the service will just close. Here is the log when it "crashes"

   ```
   WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
   WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
   WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
   Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : Could not ping any of the provided Service Fabric gateway endpoints.
   At line:1 char:8
   + [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files ...
   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricTransientException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

   WARNING: Unable to Verify connection to Service Fabric cluster.
   Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection : Cluster connection instance is null
   At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
   Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus.ps1:27 char:16
   +         [void](Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection)
   +                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection], NullReferenceException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestClusterConnection

   Finished executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'.
   Time elapsed: 00:02:04.7891918
   The program '[27216] program.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
   Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : Could not ping any of the provided Service Fabric gateway endpoints.
   At line:1 char:8
   + [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster); Import-Module 'C:\Program Files ...
   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricTransientException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster

   WARNING: Unable to Verify connection to Service Fabric cluster.
   Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection : Cluster connection instance is null
   At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
   Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus.ps1:27 char:16
   +         [void](Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection)
   +                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Test-ServiceFabricClusterConnection], NullReferenceException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.TestClusterConnection

   Finished executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'.
   Time elapsed: 00:02:04.7166263
   ```
2. After maybe an hour or two of having service fabric open the cluster becomes unresponsive and I'm unable to deploy any application until I reset the cluster. The logs just constantly say:

   ```
   Started executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'.
   Finished executing script 'Get-ServiceFabricApplicationStatus'.
   ```

I am also unable to open the service fabric manager via the icon in the task bar but the url http://localhost:19080/Explorer still works.

Running: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\CleanCluster.ps1 seems to reset it just fine and it works again for a couple of hours. Until (presumably) it gets to a point below where it runs out of connections and everything goes wrong.

The only logs I can seem to find on this are:
thousands of lines of this:

```
    localhost:19000-127.0.0.1:59598: failed to locate connection 1eedf052ba0 to update instance
    exceeded client connection limit: target=127.0.0.1:59598 max=1000
    localhost:19000-127.0.0.1:59597: failed to locate connection 1eedf055db0 to update instance
    Warning 2/26/2018 12:27:11 PM   Microsoft-Service Fabric    57089   EntreeServiceProxy
    Warning 2/26/2018 12:27:11 PM   Microsoft-Service Fabric    4097    Transport
    exceeded client connection limit: target=127.0.0.1:59596 max=1000
    localhost:19000-127.0.0.1:59595: failed to locate connection 1eedf0536c0 to update instance
    exceeded client connection limit: target=127.0.0.1:59595 max=1000
    exceeded client connection limit: target=127.0.0.1:59595 max=1000
    exceeded client connection limit: target=127.0.0.1:59594 max=1000
    localhost:19000-127.0.0.1:59593: failed to locate connection 1eedf052ba0 to update instance
    exceeded client connection limit: target=127.0.0.1:59593 max=1000
```

And my dns service seems to be in an unhealthy state:

```
   Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RA', Property='ReplicaOpenStatus',                         
   HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false.
   Replica had multiple failures during open on _Node_0. -2147467259
   For more information see: http://aka.ms/sfhealth
```

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this service fabric issue?